# Telephone number regex all formats

Tags: python, regex

I'm developing an expression to validate all possible phone number formats. I have 50%, it is not validating me the admitted characters by means of `* . - whitespace`

These are the rules

> It can contain open and close parenthesis ex. (55)
>
> It can contin or not '+' char ex. (+52)
>
> It can contain 2 or 3 numbers inside parenthesis ex. (+555) o (+55)
>
> It can contain whitespace between close parenthesis and the next
>   numbers ex. (55) 44332211
>
> The consecutive numbers to the parenthesis must be 6 or 8 numbers ex.
>   (55)443322 o (55)44332211
>
> The consecutive numbers to the parenthesis can contain whitespaces,
>   dashes, asterisks, or colons. ex.(55)44-33-22-11 o (55)44 33 22 11 o
>   (55)44*33*22*11 o (55)44.33.22.11
>
> The consecutive numbers to the parenthesis can be divided in groups of
>   2, 3 or 4 numbers ex. (55)5544-3322 o (55)55 44 33 22 o (555)444*333
>
> The number format can come in a row of 8, 10 o 12 numbers ex. 55443322
>   o 5544332211 o 554433221100

This is the regular expression

```
[\(]?[\+]?(\d{2}|\d{3})[\)]?[\s]?((\d{6}|\d{8})|(\d{3}[\*\.\-\s]){3}|(\d{2}[\*\.\-\s]){4}|(\d{4}[\*\.\-\s]){2})|\d{8}|\d{10}|\d{12}
```

This is a map of the regular expression
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I leave an example script, the regex I'm doing for Python, I do not know if I change a lot with JS

```js
$(function(){

  $('ul li').each(function(){
    let number = $(this).text();
    let regex = /^[\(]?[\+]?(\d{2}|\d{3})[\)]?[\s]?((\d{6}|\d{8})|(\d{3}[\*\.\-\s]){3}|(\d{2}[\*\.\-\s]){4}|(\d{4}[\*\.\-\s]){2})|\d{8}|\d{10}|\d{12}$/;
    let res = regex.test( number );
    $(this).text( $(this).text() + ' is: ' + res);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Telephone numbers
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>(55)test</li>
  <li>(55)333-test</li>
  <li>(55)test 22</li>
  <li>554433221100</li>
  <li>5544332211</li>
  <li>55443322</li>
  <li>(55)443322</li>
  <li>(55)44332211</li>
  <li>(+55)443322</li>
  <li>(+55)44332211</li>
  <li>(55)4433*2211</li>
  <li>(55)444.333</li>
  <li>(55)44-33-22-11</li>
  <li>(55)4433-2211</li>
  <li>(+55)443 322</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does it mean all your test cases should return *true*?

Comment: Only if it is specified by the rules, por example (55)test is not allowed, but 55-44-33-22-11 yes (and it is not working :()

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob there are a lot of holes in your rules. Are `(55)123-4567`, `555-123-4567`, `55-1234-56`, `+55123456`, `551-234-567` (where `55` is the international code) allowed?

Comment: It is an example, it can begin with (32) 55 is my area code

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Yes, but what should be the outcomes of those examples? Also, what about `5555*5555*5555`, `55 12-12-12` and `55 123-123`?

Comment: getting the right phone number regex is tricky business, I'd recommend reading the Regular Expressions Cookbook (see sections 3.5, 4.2, 4.3) by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan (2009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:\d{8}(?:\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)?|\(\+?\d{2,3}\)\s?(?:\d{4}[\s*.-]?\d{4}|\d{3}[\s*.-]?\d{3}|\d{2}([\s*.-]?)\d{2}\1\d{2}(?:\1\d{2})?))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1bsTTG/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an outer grouping construct:

  - `\d{8}` - 8 digits
  - `(?:\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)?` - optional 2 digits that are followed with an optional 2 digit substring (so, 8, 10 or 12 digit string can be matched)
- `|` - or

  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `\+?` - 1 or 0 pluses
  - `\d{2,3}` - 2 or 3 digits
  - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
  - `(?:` - a grouping:

    - `\d{4}` - 4 digits
    - `[\s*.-]?` - a whitespace, `*`, `.` or `-`, an optional occurrence
    - `\d{4}` - 4 digits
  - `|` - or

    - `\d{3}[\s*.-]?\d{3}` - 3  digits, a delimiter char,  3 digits
  - `|` - or

    - `\d{2}([\s*.-]?)\d{2}\1\d{2}(?:\1\d{2})?`: 2 digits, a separator char captured into Group 1, 2 digits, the same separator as in Group 1, 2 digits, and an optional sequence of the same separator char as in Group 1 and two digits
  - `)` - end of the inner grouping.
- `)` - end of the outer grouping
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: Beautiful, awesome and detailed. Thank you sensei

Comment: I won't open anothe thread, only for end this, could you tell me how is the validation when the number is +55 52 4433 2211 or 5522 3030 for example?

Comment: You are a monster! A truck full of beer is going to  your house. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (one which might be a lot easier) is to simply validate the phone number at the source, then only allow this one format on the server side.

```js
(function(){
  "use strict";
  var removeNonPhoneNumber = /\D/g;

  function formatPhoneNumber(ownSection, restOfIt){
    var newOwnSection = ownSection.replace(removeNonPhoneNumber, "");
    var newRestOfIt = restOfIt.replace(removeNonPhoneNumber, "");
    var totalLength = newOwnSection.length + restOfIt.length |0;

    var i=0, res="";
    if (totalLength > 10) {
      // includes country code
      for (; i < (totalLength - 10|0) && i < newOwnSection.length; i=i+1|0)
        res += newOwnSection.charAt(i);
      res += '-';
    }
    if (totalLength > 7) {
      // includes area code
      for (; i < (totalLength - 7|0) && i < newOwnSection.length; i=i+1|0)
        res += newOwnSection.charAt(i);
      res += '-';
    }
    if (totalLength > 4) {
      // includes local code
      for (; i < (totalLength - 4|0) && i < newOwnSection.length; i=i+1|0)
        res += newOwnSection.charAt(i);
      res += '-';
    }
    for (; i < totalLength && i < newOwnSection.length; i=i+1|0)
      res += newOwnSection.charAt(i);
    return res;
  }
  function autoStretch(evt){
    var target = evt && evt.target;
    if (!target) return;
    if (
      target.getAttribute("type") === "tel" && (
        // If selectionStart is supported OR the user is deselecting
          // the input, then validate
        typeof target.selectionStart === "number" ||
        evt.type === "blur"
      )
    ) {
      // forceful tel validation. It normalizes the number to be pretty
      var valueNow = target.value;
      var sStart=target.selectionStart|0, sEnd=target.selectionEnd|0;

      var newValue = formatPhoneNumber(valueNow, "");
      if (valueNow !== newValue) {
        target.value = newValue;

        // now properly shift around the cursor positions:
        if(typeof target.selectionStart==="number") 
          target.selectionStart = formatPhoneNumber(
            valueNow.substring(0, sStart), valueNow.substring(sStart)
          ).length|0;
        if(typeof target.selectionEnd==="number") 
          target.selectionEnd = formatPhoneNumber(
            valueNow.substring(0, sEnd), valueNow.substring(sEnd)
          ).length|0;
      }
    }
    target.style.width = '';
    target.style.width = target.scrollWidth + 'px';
  }

  var teleInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("prevent-invalid-telephone");
  for (var i=0, hookOptions={"passive":1}; i<teleInputs.length; i=i+1|0) {
    teleInputs[i].addEventListener("input", autoStretch, hookOptions);
    teleInputs[i].addEventListener("change", autoStretch, false);//for IE
  }
})();
```

```html
Enter your telephone here: <input type="tel" autocomplete="tel-area-code" pattern="([0-9]+-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" aria-label="Your telephone number" class="prevent-invalid-telephone"/>
```

The above snippet may look scary long, but rest assured that it goes down to a measly 1008 bytes after minification (only 486 bytes after zopfli gzip is applied).

```js
!function(){"use strict";function h(c,b){var d=c.replace(/\D/g,"")
b.replace(/\D/g,"");var e=d.length+b.length|0,a=0,f=""
if(10<e){for(;a<(e-10|0)&&a<d.length;a=a+1|0)f+=d.charAt(a)
f+="-"}if(7<e){for(;a<(e-7|0)&&a<d.length;a=a+1|0)f+=d.charAt(a)
f+="-"}if(4<e){for(;a<(e-4|0)&&a<d.length;a=a+1|0)f+=d.charAt(a)
f+="-"}for(;a<e&&a<d.length;a=a+1|0)f+=d.charAt(a);return f}function
l(c){var b=c&&c.target;if(b){if("tel"===b.getAttribute("type")&&("number"==typeof
b.selectionStart||"blur"===c.type)){c=b.value;var
d=b.selectionStart|0,e=b.selectionEnd|0,a=h(c,"")
c!==a&&(b.value=a,"number"==typeof b.selectionStart&&(b.selectionStart=h(
c.substring(0,d),c.substring(d)).length|0),"number"==typeof
b.selectionEnd&&(b.selectionEnd=h(c.substring(0,e),c.substring(e)).length|0))}
b.style.width="";b.style.width=b.scrollWidth+"px"}}for(var
k=document.getElementsByClassName("prevent-invalid-telephone"),g=0;g<k.length;g=g+1|0)
k[g].addEventListener("input",l,{passive:1}),k[g].addEventListener("change",l,!1)}();
```

```html
Enter your telephone here: <input type="tel" autocomplete="tel-area-code" pattern="([0-9]+-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" aria-label="Your telephone number" class="prevent-invalid-telephone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer has a lot of flaws:

- \s is not only for whitespace characters but also for \r and \n.

  ```
  +11 1111
  1111
  #This matches
  ```
- Minimum digits of a number is 8 and maximum is 12 but these digits have nothing to do with the international prefix digits:

  ```
  (+39)333 333 # 6 digits: this matches but it is not valid  
  (+39)3333 3333 3333 # 12 digits: this is valid but it does not match
  ```
- The international prefix matches only between brackets

  ```
  +39 3475 4087 18 # this is valid but doesn't match
  ```
- Regex is not trivial, long, complex and bugged for no reason.

I made this one to overcome those flaws and improve it:

```
^(?:((\+?\d{2,3})|(\(\+?\d{2,3}\))) ?)?(((\d{2}[\ \-\.]?){3,5}\d{2})|((\d{3}[\ \-\.]?){2}\d{4}))$
```

The understanding of this should be relatively easy with the good explanation provided in the accepted answer.

This is a [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnPlK3/1).